# Cordova ios 6 (6.1.1) and multiple targets

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, widget, target

In the past, Cordova had issues with multiple targets in xCode. Is this now possible to achieve?

What I would like to do is have an Ionic Cordova app and add a widget extension to it. Any tips?